# Refrigerator Side Wall Hole Closure - Need suggestions

Tags: insulation, refrigerator

In my side by side door refrigerator, there is a hole in the side wall on the right compartment that is intended for letting controllable amount of air from the lleft / freezer side of the refrigerator.. But we feel that the freezer air is doing more bad than good and want to close off that hole. The sliding control provided as can be seen from the pictures is not providing a good amount of insulation from cold. Can any one please suggest a good insulation component that can be used for closing off the hole in the side wall? I was not sure putty would be a right tool for the job or thermacol or something else. Please advise.

[Refrigerator Side Wall Hole Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBmjn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fridge side cools from the freezer side. If you cover holes, then your fridge side won't cool anymore. The fridge side doesn't have cooling coils. If you have issues where it is to cold, then you need to close it down and adjust the freezer side as well. If it is cold right there, and items directly next to it freeze, either move the items and leave that area clear, or create a funnel of sorts, to force the air up into the fridge compartment as cold air falls.

Comment: Would you know which materials /tools I could use for this purpose?

Comment: Tape a piece of paper in a upward funnel, of sheet plastic, or cut a funnel in half...lots of choices. Foam with a channel cut into it, cardboard...